# Domain login behind NAT

Tags: windows, domain, router, nat, login

**Global network:**

```
+-------------------+------------+--------------------+
| Server            | Address    | Description        |
+-------------------+------------+--------------------+
| dc.contoso.com    | 10.0.1.100 | Domain Controller  |
| dns.contoso.com   | 10.0.1.110 | Domain Name Server |
| dhcp.contoso.com  | 10.0.1.111 | DHCP Server        |
| proxy.contoso.com | 10.0.1.200 | Proxy Server       |
+-------------------+------------+--------------------+

>> Address pool of DHCP is 10.0.2.101 - 10.0.2.199
```

**Details:**

- I place a router between my computer and global network.
- Router is properly configured *(gets address from DHCP, has SRCNAT configured, is able to resolve names, and so on)*.
- Computer plugged into this router is working fine *(gets internal address like 192.168.XXX.XXX, is able to resolve names, communicate to internet through the proxy server, able to reach the DC, able to work with file servers on network, and so on)*.

**My issue**

- After rebooting the computer, I'm suddenly not able to log into domain. This worked couple of days ago and nothing changed since then from my side.
- The only workaround is plug my computer directly into global network, so I get address from 10.0.2.XXX pool.
- I'm not even able to change my domain password with CTRL+ALT+DEL. Dunno why, because this traffic is outgoing towards DC and SRCNAT is already configured.

**Questions**

- Any ideas what could be wrong?
- Am I missing any DSTNAT on the router? So far, there are no DSTNAT rules.¨

**EDIT**

Added tracing as requested in comments:

```
$ tracert dc.contoso.com

Tracing route to dc.contoso.com [10.0.1.100] over a maximum of 30 hops:
1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.10
2     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  dc.contoso.com [10.0.1.100]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Can you add the output of this command: `tracert dc.contoso.com` (from your computer) ?

Comment: Sure. Check EDIT section above.

Comment: BTW, **192.168.0.10** is address of _internal_ router interface. On the _public_ interface it gets address **10.0.2.150** from DHCP.

Comment: SCNR: NAT is not security and IPv6 exists and Windows work perfectly with IPv6.